# Magento website IE issue

Tags: magento, ie-compatibility-mode

I got an IE compatibility issue in my magento website. When i look deeper,I found that it is because of default quirks mode. I can able to get the original website when i change the quirks mode to IE standard mode. But by default quirks mode is coming.

I can able to fix this issue in html website when i define *DOCTYPE* of the page. But i am a newbie in magento. I don't know how can i define *DOCTYPE* in Magento website. I tried in some php files. But failed. Anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Is there any other solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

The DOCTYPE is defined within the template's main page templates ie 1column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml, 2columns-right.phtml, 3columns.phtml.

So in app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/templates/page/

Where package is your active package and theme the active theme.